# Heroku: Failed to install gems via Bundler despite running gem install bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I receive the following error from Heroku when I push my git on heroku:

```
Failed to install gems via Bundler
```

I have tried to circumvent the issue by running the following commands:

```
Gem install bundler
Gem install bundle update
```

But nothing changed. I still get the error message. When looking at the log I the potential following information:

```
Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.5). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

remote:        inherited_resources-1.9.0 requires ruby version >= 2.3, which is incompatible
remote:        with the current version, ruby 2.2.6p396
```

Bundler version is 1.16.6, ruby version is 2.5.1p57, rails version is 4.2.8. Any input as to how I could trouble this issue please?

EDIT
Here is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.8'
gem 'bcrypt', '3.1.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.2.0.0'
gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.4"
gem 'faker', '1.4.2'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
gem 'devise'
gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre1'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'pdf-reader'
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-remote'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'gon'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'


# Carrier Wave to upload file
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'mime-types'
gem 'net-ssh'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'open-uri-s3'
gem 'pg', '0.18.3'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'mail_form'
gem 'simple_form'

# Useful for session storege
gem 'activerecord-session_store', github: 'rails/activerecord-session_store'



group :development, :test do

  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'mocha'
end

group :production do
gem 'rails_12factor','0.0.2'
gem 'puma','2.11.1'
end
```

Comment: Can you update the question with `Gemfile`?

Comment: Rails 4.2.8 has been issued early 2017 and ruby 2.5.1 early 2018. You probably should use an older version of Ruby than this one. Rails could not be coded in order to factor in future changes of its "engine". Try ruby 2.1.9 for example. If you are coding a new app, just use current rails and ruby version: rails 5.2.1 and ruby 2.5.1.

Comment: There should never be a need to run `gem install bundler` on Heroku. If you're using the Ruby buildpack your gems should be installed automatically. (And if you do run that command your changes will be lost very quickly due to Heroku's [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).)